# TypeError: reactDevTools.connectToDevTools is not a function

Tags: react-native

I get this error after the first project run.

reactDevTools.connectToDevTools is not a function

> Requiring module
>   "node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\InitializeCore.js", which
>   threw an exception: TypeError: reactDevTools.connectToDevTools is not
>   a function

Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

WebSocket connection to

> 'ws://localhost:8081/debugger-proxy?role=debugger&name=Chrome' failed:
>   Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200

What is the reason of this error?
Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an issue with the new release of `react-devtools`

Steps to get your project to work:

1- Add this line to your package.json file in the project root directory (inside devDependencies):

```
...
"devDependencies": {
  "react-devtools-core": "3.4.2",
}
...
```

2- Remove `node_modules` folder.

3- Install `node_modules` again: `npm install` OR `yarn add`

Now the error should be resolved!

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22865#issuecomment-451402619), you just need to install react-dev-tools :

`npm install --save-dev react-devtools-core@3.4.2`

Answer (score 0):

Just disable JS Dev Mode in Dev Settings